# Telerik RadPanelBar - Bind Parent Items using GROUP

Tags: telerik, radpanelbar

I have a scenairo where I need to bind a RadPanelBar to a SQL table similar to the below structure:

```
ID, Name, Category 
1, Fred, Male 
2, Sam, Male 
3, Fred, Male 
4, Sam, Female
5, Louise, Female 
6, Tom, Male
```

I need the panelbar to be in a Category > Name structure (i.e. each name to be a child item of their gender) but can't see an easy way to do this from Telerik's examples.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Data Bindings](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/populatingwithdata/databindings/defaultcs.aspx) example and the [Hierarchical Data Binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/populatingwithdata/hierarchicalbinding/defaultcs.aspx) example.

Each item in the RadPanelBar has an **item id**. For child items you have to define a **parent id** also. The problem is that the database table does not have root items (male, female) stored as rows, so you have to add them first before binding to a RadPanelBar.

You can read the database table into a list or dataset, like in the [example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/populatingwithdata/hierarchicalbinding/defaultcs.aspx), and add the missing root items there.

Or, if you are using [declarative binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/populatingwithdata/databindings/defaultcs.aspx) (in ASPX), you can use UNION statements in a SQL query:

```
SELECT 
id
,CASE WHEN Category = 'Male' THEN -1 ELSE -2 END AS ParentID
,name
FROM table

UNION

SELECT 
-1 AS id
NULL As ParentID
'Male' AS name

UNION

SELECT 
-2 AS id
NULL As ParentID
'Female' AS name
```